# Single page - navigation animated scroll and highlighted nav bar links conflict

Tags: jquery, css

I have a single-page app. There's a script that will scroll down to the appropriate section when a navigation link is clicked. This is working fine.

```
$('nav a').click(function(){
    $('html, body').animate({
        scrollTop: $( $.attr(this, 'href') ).offset().top
    }, 700);
    return true;
});
```

I also have a script set up so that when you scroll up/down the page, the appropriate section's corresponding navigation link will be highlighted. This also works fine.

```
$(document).scroll(function(){
        positionNav('portfolio', 'nav-portfolio');
        positionNav('about', 'nav-about');
        positionNav('contact', 'nav-contact');
    });

    function positionNav(section, sectionNavID) {
        // Get bottom position of section
        var bottom = $('#' + section).position().top + $('#' + section).outerHeight(true);
        var top = $(document).scrollTop()+230;

        if(top >= $('#' + section).position().top && top <= bottom){
            $('#' + sectionNavID).addClass('active');
        } else {
            $('#' + sectionNavID).removeClass('active');
        }
    }
```

My only issue is that when I click on a navigation link--lets say I click on the last link that brings you to the bottom of the page. During the brief animated scroll to the bottom of the page, the sections along the way get highlighted one by one, as you pass over them, because of the second script.

I'd like to make it where if a nav item link is clicked, that item gets hightlighted and somehow the scrolling-highlight is disabled (but still works if you start scrolling).

Comment: If you are planning to have full screen sections I would recommend you to go for [fullPage.js](http://alvarotrigo.com/fullPage/) in which all of that is already coded. (and much more)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Bind your highlighting to a special class, maybe call it "enabled".

Before starting the scrolling animation, remove it, so the highlighting does not get triggered.

After the scrolling animation is done, add class "enabled" again to have your setup working again properly.

Example:

```
$('nav a').click(function(){
    $(yourSelector).removeClass('enable');
    $('html, body').animate({
        scrollTop: $( $.attr(this, 'href') ).offset().top
    }, 700, function(){
        $(yourSelector).addClass('enable');
    });
    return true;
});
```